Facing issues while implementing heap sort in Java
I have written the following program to implement heap sort (both ascending and descending) in Java. It has the following steps actually.

Create an array with a pre-specified size and initialise it with random integers.
Convert it into a heap.
Sort it.

However, although I think my code is logically correct, I am unable to yield the desired results. Any form of help or guidance is appreciated.
import java.util.*;

public class heapSort
{
    static int array[];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // int[] array = new int[1];

        createArray();
        int arrayLength = array.length;

        System.out.println("\nBefore sorting:");
        display(array);

        System.out.println("Sorting by heap sort:");
        System.out.println("1. Ascending");
        System.out.println("2. Descending");
        int choice = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                for(int i = (arrayLength - 2)/2; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    maxheapify(array, i);
                }

                for(int i = arrayLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // swap/delete operation
                    int temp = array[0];
                    array[0] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;

                    maxheapify(array, 0);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                for(int i = (arrayLength - 2)/2; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    minheapify(array, i);
                }

                for(int i = arrayLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // swap/delete operation
                    int temp = array[0];
                    array[0] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;

                    minheapify(array, 0);
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Program will terminate.");
                break;
        }

        System.out.println("\nAfter sorting:");
        display(array);
    }

    private static void createArray()
    {
        int arrayLength = 8;
        int lowerLimit = 0;
        int upperLimit = 10;
        array = new int[arrayLength];

        // fill the array with random integers
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new Random().nextInt(upperLimit) + lowerLimit;
        }
    }


    private static void maxheapify(int[] array, int currentIndex)
    {
        int leftChild = (2 * currentIndex + 1);
        int rightChild = (2 * currentIndex + 2);
        int largestElement = currentIndex;
        int arrayLength = array.length;

        if(leftChild < arrayLength && array[leftChild] > array[largestElement])
            largestElement = leftChild;
        if(rightChild < arrayLength && array[rightChild] > array[largestElement])
            largestElement = rightChild;

        if(largestElement != currentIndex)
        {
            int temp = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[largestElement];
            array[largestElement] = temp;

            // recursive call
            maxheapify(array, largestElement);
        }
    }

    private static void minheapify(int[] array, int currentIndex)
    {
        int leftChild = (2 * currentIndex + 1);
        int rightChild = (2 * currentIndex + 2);
        int smallestElement = currentIndex;
        int arrayLength = array.length;

        if(leftChild < arrayLength && array[leftChild] < array[smallestElement])
            smallestElement = leftChild;
        if(rightChild < arrayLength && array[rightChild] < array[smallestElement])
            smallestElement = rightChild;

        if(smallestElement != currentIndex)
        {
            int temp = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[smallestElement];
            array[smallestElement] = temp;

            // recursive call
            minheapify(array, smallestElement);
        }
    }

    private static void display(int[] array)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

I was expecting to get a sorted array in the end, but it does not yield that result.

Is the user input relevant to your problem? yes->make your code about that and remove all the other bits; no->remove the input and hardcode something. Same for the random generation bit. See also: [mre] What is your problem actually? "unable to yield the desired results" is not telling us much.

In a correct implementation of heap sort, the heap-part at the left side of the array becomes smaller, while the sorted part -- at the right -- grows until it occupies the full array. The problem in your code is that you do not reduce the heap part. Whenever you call the heapify function, it will consider the full array as the heap. This is wrong, because a value can trickle down into the non-heap part, causing havoc.
So provide an extra parameter at your maxheapify function, called arrayLength (replacing the local variable you already declared there) and pass the value of i to it in your swap-loop.
Here is the relevant change for case 1:
            case 1:
                for(int i = (arrayLength - 2)/2; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    maxheapify(array, i, arrayLength); // add argument
                }
                for(int i = arrayLength - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    // swap/delete operation
                    int temp = array[0];
                    array[0] = array[i];
                    array[i] = temp;

                    maxheapify(array, 0, i); // add argument
                }

... and the maxheapify function:
    private static void maxheapify(int[] array, int currentIndex, int arrayLength) // parameter
    {
        int leftChild = (2 * currentIndex + 1);
        int rightChild = (2 * currentIndex + 2);
        int largestElement = currentIndex;
        //int arrayLength = array.length;   *** removed

        if(leftChild < arrayLength && array[leftChild] > array[largestElement])
            largestElement = leftChild;
        if(rightChild < arrayLength && array[rightChild] > array[largestElement])
            largestElement = rightChild;

        if(largestElement != currentIndex)
        {
            int temp = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[largestElement];
            array[largestElement] = temp;

            // recursive call
            maxheapify(array, largestElement, arrayLength); // Added argument
        }
    }

